# Where are the DXL Files Stored in DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors

Does anybody know where DOORS stores DXL files? 
1- How can I access those scripts using DOORS UI? 
2-What is the storage directory on the hard drive?

Thanks

Comment: Which DXL files are you referring to? Because the majority of the program is written in DXL. Are you just looking for the addins directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The majority of the DXL scripts are located in:

`your_ibm_install_directory\Rational\DOORS\your_version\lib\dxl`

Many of the scripts in this area are encrypted though. If you want to add custom scripts to the User menu, place them in:

`your_ibm_install_directory\Rational\DOORS\your_version\lib\dxl\addins\user`

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks a bunch for the answer. I have imported a DOORS module and seems like it had come with a DXL that runs automatically and assigns some IDs to the objects in this module. Is this possible? If so, I am looking for that DXL.

Comment: No that isn't possible. The IDs are automatically assigned. When you import a module from an archive, the IDs will be the same as they were in the original module. This is so the history can be preserved and the links recreated.